# What is the maximum and minimum batch size we can use in .fit() method?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to see the effect of batch size on generalization for which I want to run my .fit() method with all the possible batch sizes.
But I was wondering what could be the constraints be on choosing batch sizes?
What does it depend on, a machine?? a dataset?

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: The machine's memory

Comment: The training batch size has a huge impact on the required GPU memory for training a neural network.

Comment: The GPU memory includes:
Parameters, optimizer’s variables, intermediate calculations, and workspace variables. So, the larger the batch size, the more samples are being propagated through the neural network in the forward pass. This results in larger intermediate calculations (e.g. layer activation outputs) that need to be stored in GPU memory. Technically speaking, the size of the activations is linearly dependent on the batch size.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of each sample and your GPU memory, if you're using it, else your RAM. Keep in mind that various other things are loaded in your memory, like the model's parameters, the graph, etc. But strictly for the size of a batch: NUM_SAMPLES * SIZE_OF_SAMPLE.

Answer (score 1):

The batch size you choose is affected by several parameters:

**Resources** - You need to choose a small enough batch size that will be able to fit inside you CPU / GPU RAM.

**Normalization** - If you use BatchNorm you should probably use a large batch size, as the BatchNorm layers learn the mean and variance of your batch. The smaller the batches are the larger the deviance between them will be.

Personally, I usually use the largest batch size possible according to my resources. In case the possible batch is small (<16) I swap BatchNorm with other normalization methods such as LayerNorm / InstanceNorm.

Comment: You 're answering on how to choose batch size and how it affects the training, I think that this isn't what the OP is asking. Not that this info isn't useful of course.

Comment: To the best of my understanding the OP wants to make a graph that shows the effects of using different batch sizes on his performance. I think it's worth noting to mind the type of normalization used, since it could cause an unfair comparison between batch sizes.

Comment: Ok, that's fair :-)

Answer (score 1):

The machine's memory.

The training batch size has a huge impact on the required GPU memory for training a neural network.

The GPU memory includes Parameters, optimizer’s variables, intermediate calculations, and workspace variables. So, the larger the batch size, the more samples are being propagated through the neural network in the forward pass. This results in larger intermediate calculations (e.g. layer activation outputs) that need to be stored in GPU memory. Technically speaking, the size of the activations is linearly dependent on the batch size

You can use some walk-around to increase the limitation:

- Data-parallelism — use multiple GPUs to train all mini-batches in parallel, each on a single GPU
- Gradient accumulation — run the mini-batches sequentially, while accumulating the gradients. The accumulated results are used to update the model variables at the end of the last mini-batch.